# How do you make your sprite not replicate itself in the screen? How do you make your sprite go away or start again, once the text appears?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So, I got stuck again, but I use this as a last resort when nothing's working after extensive research. Please don't roast me for this, I am a newbie. So, basically I am trying to make my sprite move (yoyo), but the frames keep replicating as the yoyo moves up and down. So, I don't know how to fix that. If the yoyo touches the borders of the game window, it collides and it's supposed to display a text and then the game starts over again. However, when the yoyo collides with the window border, it restarts, but the yoyo that got stuck is still being displayed and a new yoyo appears. The text is displayed but doesn't go away after 2 seconds.

```
   import pygame
   import time
   pygame.init()

   width = 900
   height = 900
   red = (255,0,0)
   text = "game over"

   screem = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

   pygame.display.set_caption("yoyo")
   clock = pygame.time.Clock()

   background = pygame.image.load("room.png").convert()
   win.blit(background, [0,0])

   yoyo= pygame.image.load("yoyo.png").convert()


  def Yoyo (x,y):
    win.blit(yoyo, [x,y])


def mainloop():
   x = 87
   y = 90


yc = 0 


  while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Exit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:


    Yoyo(x,y)
    y += yc

    if y > 23 or y < -90:

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

mainloop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: After posting code to a question (or answer), immediately select what you just pasted and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface. That will format your code properly without the risk of introducing indentation errors when you try to manually format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redraw the entire scene in every frame. This means you've to draw the background in every frame, too.

Draw (`blit`) the background in the main loop, before anything else is drawn:

```py
while not Exit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Exit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame. K_DOWN:
                y_change = 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 0 

  y += y_change
  if y > 405 or y < -200:
      collision()
  GameLoop() 

  win.blit(bg, [0,0]) # <----- draw background
  Bee(x,y)            # <----- draw the bee on the background

  # [...] all further drawing has to be done here

  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(60)
```